# My header has disappeared/lost its formatting; Its suddenly not applying some of the custom css

Tags: css, formatting, header

RE: https://heritagecountrypottery.com
My header has disappeared/lost its formatting; its suddenly not applying some of the custom css.
I am using Intuition Pro who have gone bust so I cannot ask their developers.
The header should look like this... http://garryrigby.com/no-header.jpg
I restored the website oo March 12th when everything was working fine. In a few hours I lose the header again

Comment: it's like your header svg is white on white bg (maybe dark mode image is used by mistake?)

Comment: It is supposed to be dark background. I moved the custom css to a different location and it is now working